# My Q was marked as duplicate, but I already explained how solution for the older Q does not work for my Q

Tags: discussion

My question:
[How can I use an already installed module when I'm using a virtual environment?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58472/how-can-i-use-an-already-installed-module-when-im-using-a-virtual-environment)

was marked as a duplicate of:
[RPi.GPIO not found in virtual environment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58186/rpi-gpio-not-found-in-virtual-environment)

But I had already stated in my question that installing the module in the environment doesn't work, which was the solution to the question mine was marked as a duplicate of.
Thus I believe that my question is not a duplicate.

I have edited my question to further show how my problem is not solved by the solutions for the other question.

Answer (score 6):

I closed that.  I would not have closed the current version (I've reopened that), which explicitly states that you tried `pip` in the virtual environment and what the complication seems to be there.  The original only mentions `apt`.

All apologies and good luck!